# Use Typescript to describe a class with dynamically added properties

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I'm trying to add Typescript definitions to an existing codebase which happens to use the Knockout library. The code contains a very common pattern which looks like this:

```
interface SomeProperties {
    // A bunch of properties
}

class ViewModel {
    // Some properties of my own...

    constructor(data: SomeProperties) {
        AddAllPropertiesToThis(data);
    }
}
```

Where `AddAllPropertiesToThis` takes the data object and dynamically adds all of its properties to `this`.

I can't figure out how to express this pattern in Typescript. It makes sense to say something like

```
class ViewModel implements SomeProperties
```

but this requires manually copying all of the properties from the interface definition into the class.

Is there any way to accomplish what I need to do here without having to type out redundant properties?

Comment: did you ever managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a member variable `data: SomeProperties` in ViewModel.

```
interface SomeProperties {
    // A bunch of properties
}

class ViewModel {
    data: SomeProperties;

    constructor(data: SomeProperties) {
        // deep copy the data
        this.data = { ...data };
    }
}
```

To me it makes more sense to do it by way of composition as the code above rather than inheritance. The `ViewModel` contains (has) `SomeProperties`. It is not an extension of `SomeProperties` ("is a" relationship).

Comment: Agreed, composition over inheritance seems like a better idea.

Comment: This would be great however it's not really possible - it would change the API in way too many places to be feasible. Any existing reference to these object properties (even in the markup seeing as this is Knockout) would have to change.